# Como traduzir o agenda header do Full Calendar?

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc, fullcalendar

Saudações, amigos do Stack Overflow!
Estou a um passo de completar uma agenda utilizando o fantástico plugin do [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), no qual fico grato por existir. Porém, estou tendo alguns problemas de tradução com ele:

Infelizmente, a propriedade locale/language não está funcionando corretamente no meu código (estou usando C# com MVC5 e JS), logo, estou tendo que traduzir na mão:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio',
        'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro',
        'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua',
        'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],

    defaultDate: new Date(),
    locale: 'pt-BR',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek'
    },
    columnFormat: 'ddd',
```

Até o momento está tudo supimpa, porém a única coisa que não estou conseguindo traduzir desta maneira é o "Agenda Header" - O danado se recusa a ficar em português, e não consegui encontrar na documentação/em outros sites uma maneira de formatar apenas esta propriedade.

Aqui tem uma imagem que mostra o que eu quero dizer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero traduzir aquela partezinha do Dec 31, 2017 - Jan  6, 2018 para o português, e para o formato correto, mas como eu já disse, a propriedade **Locale** não está funcionando.

Outra coisa:

Estou ciente que a propriedade Locale só funciona com os JS de idiomas (pt-br.js) sendo chamados corretamente. Ele está devidamente referenciado na pasta locale e no BundleScript usado para este calendário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá eu fiz da seguinte forma para traduzir tudo

ao descompactar o zip fullcalendar, você terá o endereço:
fullcalendar/locale/pt-br.js.

faça a chamada do arquivo na página em questão

```
<script src='js/fullcalendar361/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar361/locale/pt-br.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar361/lib/moment.min.js'></script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // no script setar "pt-br"
        locale:  'pt-br',
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Infelizmente esta foi uma das primeiras coisas que fiz e não deu certo, Wilson! Talvez seja algum problema com o MVC, pois se eu fizer em um arquivo separado via Script direto, isso funciona.

Obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Alterei o código que fiz para incluir as chamadas dos scripts, você tentou desta forma também?